# Excel - to automatically select a cell that finds a matching year and number

Tags: excel, select, cell

```
Row 1:  2013                2014                
Row 2:  1   2   3   4   5   1   2   3   4   5
```

I have these two rows in excel (the second row is actually the no of week in the year); two merged cells in row 1 and 10 cells in row 2. (Sorry I don't know how to format it nicely here)

The criteria is as follow. There is a cell, say cell C1, to indicate the year, and another cell C2 to indicate the no of the week. My question is that how can i get excel to automatically select a cell in row 2 matching the criteria stated in cell C1 and cell C2? Cell C1 and C2 are inputs by user.

I hope it's understandable, I have tried to explain it as clear as possible but please let me know if the question is not clear. This is all done in Excel.

Appreciate any kind answer to my problem above. Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "moving" a cell (in title) and by "automatically selecting" a cell (paragraph 2)? It would also be helpful if you would provide more information on the kinds of criteria you want to apply.

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1 I have put the year 2013. This cell is merged with cell B1. In cell G1 I have put year 2014. This again is merged with cell H1. These two cells are in Row 1. Below these cells under each year I have entered 1,2,3,4,5 in seperate cells indicating weeks.
The user inputs year in Cell C5 and week number in Cell C6.
I have put a command button below the input cells to enable user click after entering values. In the Command button click event I have written the following code:

```
For i = 1 To 5
If Cells(5, 3) = Cells(1, 1) And Cells(2, i) = Cells(6, 3) Then
Cells(2, i).Activate
End If
Next
For j = 6 To 10
If Cells(5, 3) = Cells(1, 7) And Cells(2, j) = Cells(6, 3) Then
Cells(2, j).Activate
End If
```

Next

Now after entry of year and week, with the click of button the cell containing the week number under the corresponding year is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain further how do you put a command button? And by below the input cells, do you mean cell C7?

Answer (score 0):

Below the input cell means either Cell C7 or C8 or C10.
The command button can be drawn from Veiw menu - Tool Bars - Visual Basic. When you get the menu bar of the visual basic tools just drag the command button on to Cell C7 or C8 and resize it and give a meaningful caption.
When the button is double clicked it opens the code window onto which you can copy the code I have given under Command_Button_Doubleclick Event.
Then you can run the code and get the work done.